# separating a line into two in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have to make a code that splits the username by the domain.

ex.

**Input**: abc@xyz.com

**Output**: Your username is abc.
        Your domain is xyz.com.

The outcome is suppose to by in **two** different lines but i can't seem to get that...

```
def username2(email):
    z=(email.split('@'))
    x='Your username is'+ ' ' + z[0]
    y='Your domain is' + ' ' + z[1]
    return x+'. '+y+'.'
```

Sorry.. I'm really noob.

Answer (score 4):

You need to insert a newline character into your result:

```
return x + '. \n' + y + '.'
```

You could also use string formatting:

```
username, domain = email.split('@')

return 'Your username is {}.\nYour domain is {}.'.format(username, domain)
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape codes are what you're looking for

print "first line \nSecond Line"

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals

Answer (score 0):

Python3

```
def username2(email):
    username, domain = email.split('@')
    print('Your username is {}'.format(username))
    print('Your domain is {}'.format(domain))
```

Python2

```
def username2(email):
    username, domain = email.split('@')
    print 'Your username is %s' % username
    print 'Your domain is %s' % domain
```